# Fine-tuning Universal Sentence Encoder with LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

The input data:

```
string_1_A, string_2_A, string_3_A, label_A
string_1_B, string_2_B, string_3_B, label_B
...
string_1_Z, string_2_Z, string_3_Z, label_Z
```

and I would like to use Universal Sentence Encoder (v4) to get an embedding of that string (will be sentences) and then feed it into LSTM to make a prediction about that sequence. I end up with code below:

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM


module_url = "../resources/embeddings/use-4"

def get_lstm_model():
    embedding_layer = hub.KerasLayer(module_url)

    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(3, ), dtype=tf.string)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda y: tf.expand_dims(embedding_layer(tf.squeeze(y)), 1))(inputs)
    x = LSTM(128, return_sequences=False)(x)
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    model.compile("adam",  K.binary_crossentropy)
    model.summary()
    return model


if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = get_lstm_model()
    print(model.predict([[["a"], ["b"], ["c"]]]))
```

the problem is that the dimension of input/output of certain layers does not match as I expected (instead of 1 I would expect 3):

```
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 3)]               0         
_________________________________________________________________
lambda (Lambda)              (None, ***1***, 512)            0
```

Any suggestion - I think I need to better handle squeezing and unsqueezing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to pass each string/sentence **separately** into the Universal Sentence Encoder. This produces an embedding for each string/sentence of shape 512 that can be concatenated to form a tensor of shape (None, n_sentences, 512).

This is the code of the model:

```
n_sentences = 50
module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4"

def get_lstm_model():
    embedding_layer = hub.KerasLayer(module_url, trainable=True)

    input = Input(shape=(n_sentences,), dtype=tf.string)
    x = [Reshape((1,512))(embedding_layer(input[:, s])) for s in range(n_sentences)]
    x = Concatenate(axis=1)(x)
    x = LSTM(128, return_sequences=False)(x)
    output = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)

    model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
    model.compile("adam", "binary_crossentropy")
    model.summary()
    return model
```

At inference time:

```
sentences = [str(i) for i in range(n_sentences)]
X = [sentences] # 1 sample
print(model.predict(X).shape)

X = [sentences, sentences[::-1]] # 2 samples
print(model.predict(X).shape)
```

[Here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1mfs2mZTrbRQQ6aF_rvWJMx0uejJGz-nK?usp=sharing) the running notebook

Comment: @United121 see my updates where I provided u the example to deal with 50 sentences

Comment: I was a little bit worried about the warnings (of not using KerasLayer in the Lambda) so I changed it to this version - [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zvEzoT3NNUMXOtz901HPAxF1S7W_QZjy?usp=sharing). Do you think it is correct because of reshaping - I am not sure if the dimension will be valid at the end and that I am not mixing all vectorc together?

Comment: and it also seems like a pretty slow solution

Comment: U can substitute Lambda + expand_dim with Reshape to suppress warnings (see edits). the more the sentences the slower the computation. This is normal. But you should test it in a more complex case. However, I think it's the right track